# MYSQL NOT IN Query not working unless hard coded

Tags: php, mysql

I'm fairly new to Javascript and PHP so I have no idea what I'm doing for the most part. I'm trying to make a Room Booking System.

```
$booking_id = '';
if(isset($_POST['edit_button_booking'])){
    $booking_id = $_POST['edit_id'];
}

echo "<script>alert('$booking_id')</script>";

$today_date = date('Y-m-d');
$room_query = "SELECT * FROM rooms";
$room_run = $conn->query($room_query);
if($room_run->num_rows>0){
    $options = mysqli_fetch_all($room_run, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}

$start_from = 8;
$end_from = 21;
$start_to = $start_from+1;
$end_to = $end_from+1;
$from_booked = [];
$to_booked = [];
if(isset($_POST['value'])){
    $room_id = $_POST['value'];
    $specify_query = "SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE room_id = '$room_id'";
    $specify_run = $conn->query($specify_query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($specify_run);
    $room_name = $row['room_name'];
    $disable_query = "SELECT booking_id, room_id, booking_date, booking_start, booking_end FROM booking WHERE booking_date = '$today_date' AND room_id = '$room_id' AND booking_id NOT IN (SELECT booking_id FROM booking WHERE booking_id = '$booking_id')";
    $disable = $conn->query($disable_query);
    if($disable->num_rows > 0){
        while($row = $disable->fetch_assoc()){
            $from_booked_hour = date_parse($row['booking_start'])['hour'];
            $to_booked_hour = date_parse($row['booking_end'])['hour'];
            $from_booked = array_merge($from_booked, range($from_booked_hour, $to_booked_hour-1));
            $to_booked = array_merge($to_booked, range($from_booked_hour+1, $to_booked_hour));
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code. What this code is supposed to do is to display the booked time slots for the room except for the chosen time slot.

[image]
[image]
And yet, it keeps on displaying both booked times when I want the 9 -12 time slot to be omitted from the time table
The alert that I used show that $booking_id has the value '000053' which is the id of the booking that I want not shown in the time table.
If I were to hard code it to $booking_id = '000053' or $booking_id = 53, it works.

```
$booking_id = '';
if(isset($_POST['edit_button_booking'])){
    $booking_id = $_POST['edit_id'];
}

$booking_id = 53;

echo "<script>alert('$booking_id')</script>";

$today_date = date('Y-m-d');
$room_query = "SELECT * FROM rooms";
$room_run = $conn->query($room_query);
if($room_run->num_rows>0){
    $options = mysqli_fetch_all($room_run, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}

$start_from = 8;
$end_from = 21;
$start_to = $start_from+1;
$end_to = $end_from+1;
$from_booked = [];
$to_booked = [];
if(isset($_POST['value'])){
    $room_id = $_POST['value'];
    $specify_query = "SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE room_id = '$room_id'";
    $specify_run = $conn->query($specify_query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($specify_run);
    $room_name = $row['room_name'];
    $disable_query = "SELECT booking_id, room_id, booking_date, booking_start, booking_end FROM booking WHERE booking_date = '$today_date' AND room_id = '$room_id' AND booking_id NOT IN (SELECT booking_id FROM booking WHERE booking_id = '$booking_id')";
    $disable = $conn->query($disable_query);
    if($disable->num_rows > 0){
        while($row = $disable->fetch_assoc()){
            $from_booked_hour = date_parse($row['booking_start'])['hour'];
            $to_booked_hour = date_parse($row['booking_end'])['hour'];
            $from_booked = array_merge($from_booked, range($from_booked_hour, $to_booked_hour-1));
            $to_booked = array_merge($to_booked, range($from_booked_hour+1, $to_booked_hour));
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
I don't know what is causing this issue. Any help will be appreciated.

The var_dump of both queries are as follows:

Generated SQL:

```
string(156) "SELECT booking_id, room_id, booking_date, booking_start, booking_end FROM booking WHERE booking_date = '2022-07-22' AND room_id = '1' AND booking_id != '53'"
```

Hard Coded:

```
string(156) "SELECT booking_id, room_id, booking_date, booking_start, booking_end FROM booking WHERE booking_date = '2022-07-22' AND room_id = '1' AND booking_id != '53'"
```

UPDATE:

The var_dump()'s I posted earlier were outside of the `if(isset($_POST['value']))` block since I thought the variable `$booking_id` can be accessed in the if block as well. I tried to use var_dump() inside the if block and it turned out that the $booking_id was turning up blank.

```
string(154) "SELECT booking_id, room_id, booking_date, booking_start, booking_end FROM booking WHERE booking_date = '2022-07-22' AND room_id = '1' AND booking_id != ''"
```

This was the result of the var_dump() running inside of the if block. I don't understand why it is doing this though. My `$today_date` variable was defined outside of the if block as well and that's working.

Comment: **Warning**: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterised **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. [Escaping is not enough](https://phpdelusions.net/top#escaping)

Comment: $booked_id was an attempt to use a for loop to try and hard code the value to be the same as the $booking_id. I scraped that idea since it didn't work either. It still doesn't work with $booking_id in the query

Comment: Yes, I've tried both and both produced the desired output

Comment: `echo` the generated SQL out and compare it to the hard-coded

Comment: I did as you asked but the output of the generated SQL and the hard coded are the exact same.

Comment: Your queries are identical. It's literally impossible for them to return different results for the same data / state